# "No boot device available" W10, Dell Inspiron

Tags: boot, windows-10, partitioning

I have a brand new (!) **Windows 10** machine and it was fine until I tried to install **Ubuntu 14** alongside W10 ... I created a 455Gb partition in the free space (only 1 HDD), created Root, Swap and Home partitions, but decided against committing to the Ub installation, as I was not confident that it would not overwrite the W10.  So I clicked on the **Revert** button in the Ub installation screen, quit the installation and restarted the PC ... and now it won't start Windows.  I get the message, "*No boot device available*" and a list:

SATA 0 - Installed
SATA 1 - None
SATA 2 - Installed
SATA 3 - None

I went into the BIOS and disabled the Secure Boot mode, switched from UEFI to Legacy ... still no joy.  I used a command prompt to force an MBR boot sector ... no go.

I tried using the **Recovery Disk** (a flash drive) but got, "*A required drive partition is missing*" after attempting repair, and there were no images I could revert to.  (Leading me to wonder wtf is the point of the "Recovery" disk.)

Can anyone help me please?!  Thanks in advance for any advice.

Jack.

Comment: Sounds like you've flubbed your partitions and damaged/overwritten the Windows partition. I would format the drive and reinstall Windows from scratch since you're not exactly sure what the current state of the drive is or what you've done to get it to this state.

Comment: Thanks, man, appreciate your input, I was coming to the same conclusion ...